# Facebook staff can't login to approve my action type...what now?

Tags: facebook, authentication, facebook-opengraph

I recently submitted a request for two open graph action types to be approved after successfully testing the action type in my feed. However I am getting the following message from facebook:

> Changes needed Please make the changes below and resubmit for review.
>   We were unable to successfully log-in to your app with the 'Login with
>   Facebook' button or we were unable to locate the button within your
>   app. Please ensure that you can successfully log-in to Facebook with
>   the Facebook connect button and resubmit.
>   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication

I seem to be able to login and create a new account on my own and so can my friend, and from the submitted pictures it seems to be obvious where to click facebook connect to login...what can I do now to provide more information?

In case anybody is curious, the website is: www.bigfunny.com  Thanks!

Comment: Is Sandbox mode disabled for this app?

Comment: Yes Sandbox mode is disabled.